# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "uuid" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, uuid

This is probably a very simple question, but I can't figure it out even after reading many articles. I don't know any Node.js, and I just want to use the uuid generator from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

When I follow the instruction and put

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4();
```

The browser tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "uuid". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."
I'm guessing maybe I need to import some .js file from "node_module", so I opened the node_module and only see a lot of files that I don't understand at all. This is very frustrating, and the same problem may occur when I try to use any other npm modules in the future.

Comment: Did you install the module using NPM? Can you see it in your package.json file?

Comment: Yes I did. I can see the "uuid" in package.json's dependencies

Comment: And you’re all set up for ES6 transpiling? Did you try using the CommonJS require?

Comment: Yeah I tried using require() as well, didn't work. I'm really beginning to learn all these and don't know much about these terms. I think I might need other modules such as require.js or browsify, or learn node.js in the future.

Comment: You say `The browser tells me …` but earlier you talk about nodejs. Where how do you execute that JavaScript code?

Comment: Everything is in the browser. I guess I talked about how I don't know node.js, or maybe I used code intended for node.js instead of browser. connexo's answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run JavaScript in browser, while using Node.js.

Probably you should either run the code using Node.js, or tell the browser where it may find your module.

### Using Node.js

Put your code into some file, like `index.js` and run it using:

```bash
$ cd dir/with/your/file
$ node index.js
```

You'd better add some `console.log` to get the result. Otherwise Node.js will just eval your code and exit.

### In browser

As I said, browser should know the path where your `uuid` module is placed. It does not know anything about this module. It needs the path to JS file.

There are two ways: bundle deps or use import maps.

To bundle deps you need to install a bundler — a tool which will get the JavaScript code of every dep (`uuid` in your case), put it into one big JS file and give you this file. Then you may run such a file in a browser.

The most popular bundler is [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), so maybe you should start with it. Or google about Parcel, Vite, esbuild, Rollup, and so on. They all solve similar problems related to bundling.

Another way is just to tell the browser where to find your dep. E.g. like this we can tell it that your dep is on Skypack CDN:

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "uuid": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/uuid"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Read more about import maps in [this 101 article](https://uploadcare.com/blog/import-maps-101/).

Hope it helps.